# target 'toggle' links in Bootstrap navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap 3 framework to create a nag. I can target the regular nave with my css, but can't seem to target the links when they are in toggle/mobile mode. * I am using Bootstrap CDN. brought in from host

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">

    <nav class="navbar navbar-custom" role="navigation">

         <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->

            <div class="navbar-header">

                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse"> 
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                </button> 

                <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"></a>

            </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling --> 

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse navbar-right"> 
                <?php /* Primary navigation */
                    wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu' => 'top_menu',
                    'depth' => 2,
                    'container' => false,
                    'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    //Process nav menu using our custom nav walker
                    'walker' => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                    );
                ?>
            </div>
    </nav>

</div>
</div> <!--/container -->
```

CSS - changing values in these fields doesn't affect the type.

```
.navbar-custom  ul.dropdown-menu {
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu li a {
}

.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

what css changes do I need to be able to style the drop down links properties

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I apologize the question is right above the CSS, the css doesn't affect the links when in toggle mode

Answer (score 0):

a simple bootstrap navbar , with a dropdown `li` has the following structure :

```
<li class="dropdown open">
    <a aria-expanded="true" href="#lala" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
       Java 
       <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="listbox">
       <li><a href="#lala1" role="option">jmeter</a></li>
       <li><a href="#lala2" role="option">EJB</a></li>
       <li><a href="#lala3" role="option">Jasper Report</a></li>
       <li><a href="#" role="option">One more separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

and bootstrap uses the following selector to add styles to the dropdown items I.E. The `a` tags in the dropdown :

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    display: block;
    padding: 3px 20px;
    clear: both;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.42857;
    color: #333;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

The hover and focus styles like so :

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #262626;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}
```

Notice how bootstrap is using the **>** selector and you are NOT ! .

Also in mobile mode , the bootstrap selector change as follows :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #777;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
    color: #333;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

So may be you can do something like :

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover {
   // your code goes here .
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
        // your code  goes here . 
    }
```

Comment: I am using it with Wordpress, hence why the code has php etc involved. I tried the code you used to no avail

Comment: @user3550879 have your site on live ? can you share a link ?

Comment: unfortunately i do not, it's still on local host

Comment: @user3550879 can you post the generated HTML from the developer tools ? , of only the navbar code !